# Is it possible to convert my react native app like codes to apk like I don't need to use Android studio

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I wanted to know how to actually generate or to make my native app an apk like I wanted to try if  can download it and use it .Like it's almost done but still wanna know how can i let my friends download and use it without scanning the qr code because this app should work offline and expo is just for testing and ofcourse you have to use data for that

Trying to find solutions but still I need I help I'm stuck with this

Comment: Have you tried searching for "react native build release APK"? From what I understand this seems to be your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a debug version of your app and then share the generated apk file with your friends however you desire. To generate the debug mode go through the following steps:

Step 1: In your project's root directory run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Step 2: Go to android directory:

```
cd android
```

Step 3: Now in this directory, run:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

It will take a few minutes until apk file is ready.
After a successful build, you can find the apk file in this path:
projectName/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

**HINT: keep in mind you should use newer versions of react-native. (This feature is available after version > 0.58)**